# NetBeans doesn't scan "large" (350 KB+) javascript files

Tags: javascript, netbeans, large-files, large-file-support

I have large (about 6 MB) javascript file which contains library api+documentation like that:

```
/**
 * Function doc
 */
library.class.func=function(something){};

/**
 * Function 2 doc
 */
library.class.func2=function(something){};
```

And I need to use this file for code auto-completion in NetBeans 8.0. I know that NetBeans will stop scanning file with code if it's bigger than 1 MB, and this behavior is probably documented somewhere. However, for me it stops scanning file absolutely randomly, even if its size is less than 1 MB. Sometimes it stops scanning 350 KB file, sometimes it works for 400 KB file. I have no idea why.

I solved this problem writing simple python script to split javascript file into chunks, and it works if I split file into ~300 KB chunks (I found the size experimentally).

However, it's is really, REALLY annoying to have 20 different files. Today is 2014, humans are traveling into space, we are sending code to rover located on Mars surface, but NetBeans can't parse 6 MB file.

Is there any settings or any other way to force Netbeans to scan large (at least up to 10 MB) javascript file? Or maybe I should change my IDE?

Comment: Sending code to Mars?  64k should be enough for anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSettingHeapSize

Try to set a bigger JVM heap size for `Netbeans`.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Doesn't help, at least for 6 MB files. I didn't check if it solves the problem for <1MB files, because it doesn't matter.